# DSGridView select row programmatically

Tags: c#

I'm using the DSGRIDview (https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/dsgridview) as alternative for the Datagridview for my android app. Anyone has an idea how to select a row programmatically in this control?

Comment: Doc page says there's a `SelectedIndex` property

Comment: Yes but i can't find it, even not in the examples...

Comment: i found the solution: gridviewName.Processor.SelectedIndex = selectedIndexYouWant;